# Label in cell positioned in the very upper-left corner?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

It's very odd - my cell labels are looking something like this:

[image]

However my constraints are set as such: [image]

[image]

If I remove the constraints completely, then it's working. But I tested on multiple platforms and on both the simulator and an actual device. I've tried multiple combinations of constraints, none of which seem to work. This hasn't happened to me before, albeit I haven't done much iOS programming in a while. Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong or new in XCode 9?

**Edit:** I was able to fix by deleting and adding back a new UITableViewController and recreating it, but it's very odd and I'm wondering why this could be in the first place.

Comment: I would have thought of an issue about the superview/tableview leading to the safearea/superview and/witouth "margin" selected.

Comment: try with Alignment constraint  : Vertically in Container

Comment: @NaumanMalik like center vertically in containment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the custom class for your Content View, one level below your cell.  If the Content View is a subclass of UITableCellView instead of UIView, you'll see this behavior.  Unless you're sure you want to create a custom class for the Content View versus the cell itself, make sure not to use a Custom Cell here, in which case your Custom Class for the ContentView will be set to UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this constraint on label
[image]